# Encryption at Rest for Source Code on Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I had someone reach out to me with a couple of queries about source code encryption in Team Services. I don't know and can't find an answer to online (Google fell flat?).

The question is: Can a company control their own encryption of source code at rest with Team services? Essentially, this would mean controlling their own keys and having the ability to pull access logs for people accessing the source control.

I believe the answer is still no. Microsoft may encrypt, but I don't believe there is a provision for a company to control their own source control security if it goes on the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just as what you think: No for now. Microsoft use kinds of ways ([Check this link for details: Visual Studio Team Services Data Protection](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/vso-security-whitepaper)) to protect the customer data, but the way which you are asking isn't supported for now.

You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eddie. I reached out someone inside Microsoft and it appears this is on the roadmap, but not as my client desires. But I think we might get something worked out.